# How can I call a static method in a Ruby module from a class that includes the module?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to declare static methods in a module in ruby?

```
module Software
  def self.exit
    puts "exited"
  end
end

class Windows
  include Software

  def self.start
    puts "started"
    self.exit
  end
end

Windows.start
```

The example above will not print out "exited".

Is it only possible to have instance methods in a module?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Define your module like this (i.e. make `exit` an instance method in the module):

```
module Software
  def exit
    puts "exited"
  end
end
```

and then use `extend` rather than `include`

```
class Windows
  extend Software
  # your self.start method as in the question
end
```

In use:

```
irb(main):016:0> Windows.start
started
exited
=> nil
```

**Explanation**

> [*obj*.extend(module, ...)](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000335) adds to
>   *obj* the instance methods from each module given as a parameter

...so when used within the context of a class definition (with the class itself as the receiver) the methods become class methods.

Answer (score 22):

Put your class methods in a nested module, and then override the "included" hook.  This hook is called anytime your module is included.  Inside the hook, add the class methods to whomever did the include:

```
module Foo

  def self.included(o)
    o.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def foo
      'foo'
    end

  end

end
```

Now any class including Foo gets a class method named foo:

```
class MyClass
  include Foo
end

p MyClass.foo    # "foo"
```

Any non-class methods may be defined in Foo as usual.

Comment: (beside: it's MyClass.foo )
This approach has the advantage, that you can add non-static functions, too.

Comment: @Baju, either `::` or `.` works there, but I suppose `.` is preferred.  I've edited the example.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: -1. Yuck, this is completely unnecessary. Just use `extend` instead of `include`.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, I'm not sure I agree.  This allows instance methods and class methods at the same time.

Comment: Uglier implementation of the module, but better encapsulation.[pa

Answer (score 2):

Two things need to change to be able to call `Windows.exit`:

1. `Software#exit` needs to be an instance method
2. `Windows` needs to `extend` `Software`, not `include` it.

This is because `extend`ing another module puts that module's instance methods as the current module's *class* methods, whereas `include`ing a module puts the methods as new instance methods.

```
module Software
    def exit
        puts "exited"
    end
end

class Windows
    extend Software

    def self.start
        puts "started"
        self.exit
    end

end

Windows.start
```

Output is:

```
started
exited
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to include static methods in a module:

```
module Software

  def self.exit
    puts "exited"

  end
end

Software.exit
```

Running this prints 'exited' as expected.

Comment: but do i have to include this module inside the class for using the static method? cause include does just include instance methods from a module not static?

Comment: Ah, not sure on that one. An easy fix would be just to call 'Software.exit' inside the Windows class and get rid of the 'include Software' part (not the most elegant fix, but outside of the scope of this question as currently posed).